# How to hash the password using bcrypt in django?

Tags: django, bcrypt

I am converting php website to django. I have to match the password of a user during login.
For hashing the password in cakephp

```
Security::setHash('blowfish');
Security::setCost(7);
```

Now I have to find same hashing function in django. I went through the [this](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html)  and found out that they use bcrypt to hash the password in CakePhp. I am beginner in Django and Can not figure out how to encrypt the password using bcrypt in Django specially setCost() function so that hashed password is same as in CakePhp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#using-bcrypt-with-django

> Using bcrypt with Django
>
> 1. Install the [bcrypt library](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/). This can be done by running `python -m pip install django[bcrypt]`, which is equivalent to `python -m pip install bcrypt` (along with any version requirement from Django’s setup.cfg).
> 2. Modify `PASSWORD_HASHERS` to list `BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher` first. That is, in your settings file, you’d put:
>
> ```
> PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
>     'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
> ]
> ```

Now, when using the django `User` class, bcrypt would be used to hash the passwords when calling the [User.set_password()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I used   bcrypt.hashpw()  and  bcrypt.checkpw()  .